# How come j is not incremented in this example?

Tags: c

C newbie here, and I'm wondering, how come j is not incremented in the example below?

I searched everywhere for an explanation

```
int i, j, k;
i = 3; j=4; k=5;

_Bool checkbit;

checkbit = i < j || ++j < k;

printf("%d\n", checkbit );
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j , k);
```

The output is

```
1
3 4 5
```

instead of

```
1
3 5 5
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's because of your logic, the first statement is true so `checkbit` becomes 1.

Comment: @H2CO3 [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @Kevin Damn. Thanks, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it doesn't need to be evaluated.

```
checkbit = i < j || ++j < k;
```

`i < j` will yield `true`, so no matter what the second part of the expression yields, the value of `checkbit` will be `true`. Thus, it doesn't even bother evaluating it.

---

Just for kicks:

```
checkbit = i > j && ++j < k;
```

In this case, the second expression will not be evaluated because `false && (expr)` is `false`.

Answer (score 5):

Double-Or is "Shortcutting" - it won't evaluate the rest of the expression if the first part is true.
Use a single-or to increment it whatever happens.

This can be useful sometimes. It speeds up execution, because if the first part is true, you **know** the result of the `or` must be true!

Note that this is the same (in reverse) for `&&`: If the first part of && is false, then the second part is ignored, as you know the result will be false.

Answer (score 3):

And it's perhaps worth mentioning that this behavior, [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), is in the C standard:

> 6.5.14 Logical OR operator
>   Syntax
>
> 1 logical-OR-expression:
>   logical-AND-expression
>   logical-OR-expression || logical-AND-expression
>
> Constraints
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have scalar type.
>
> Semantics
>
> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields 0. The result has type int.
>   4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is
>   a sequence point after the evaluation of the ﬁrst operand. **If the ﬁrst operand compares
>   unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

When using || operator, and the first condition evaluates to true, it ignores the rest unlike the && operator

```
 checkbit = i < j || ++j < k; //since i < j is true, it skips over ++j < k
```